# Big-O notation and polynomials?

Tags: algorithm, function, math, big-o, proof

So I have this problem to do and I am not really sure where to start:

Using the definition of Big-O, prove the following:

1. T(n) = 2n + 3 ∈ O(n)
2. T(n) = 5n + 1 ∈ O(n<sup>2</sup>)
3. T(n) = 4n<sup>2</sup> + 2n + 3 ∈ O(n<sup>2</sup>)

if anyone can point me in the right direction (you don't necessarily have to give me the exact answers), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This follows pretty easily from "the definition of Big-O".  Which part of your homework are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same trick to solve all of these problems.  As a hint, use the fact that

> If a ≤ b, then for any n ≥ 1, n<sup>a</sup> ≤ n<sup>b</sup>.

As an example, here's how you could approach the first of these: If n ≥ 1, then 2n + 3 ≤ 2n + 3n = 5n.  Therefore, if you take n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and c = 5, you have that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> that 2n + 3 ≤ 5n.  Therefore, 2n + 3 = O(n).

Try using a similar approach to solve the other problems.  For the second problem, you might want to use it twice - once to upper-bound 5n + 1 with some linear function, and once more to upper bound that linear function with some quadratic function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but could you further clarify the difference between `2n + 3` and `5n + 1` for this purpose? They look like they're of the same form to me.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I do have one question though:

I see your correlation between [n^a <= n^b] and [2n+3 <= 2n + 3n = 5n], but how did you come up with 2n + 3n?

Comment: @Geobits- In the OP's question, the goal is to prove 2n + 3 = O(n) and 5n + 1 = O(n^2).  It's not that 5n + 1 is different from 2n + 3 as much as the upper bounds required are different.

Comment: @user2839411- 3 = 3n^0.  The idea is to show that 3 = 3n^0 <= 3n^1 = 3n assuming that n >= 1.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @templatetypedef- ah ok, now I think I get it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're saying it's enough to prove that `5n+1` falls *under* O(n^2), then it makes sense. If someone asked me the big-O of 5N+1, I'd say O(n), using the same logic. It still grows in relation to `n`, not `n^2`.

Comment: @Geobits- Since big-O notation just gives an asymptotic upper bound, we can upper bound it with O(n), O(n^2), O(n!), O(2^2^2^n), etc.  Those last few ones aren't tight bounds, but they're technically correct.

Comment: Gotcha. And this is why I hate lax bounds.